# Are the minified version of bootstrap equivalent to the raw files?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed bootstrap comes with `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` in addition to the raw files.

Do I need to be including both in my app, or is the minified version just a compressed version to minimize the file size?

Comment: Yes. `The minified version is just a compressed version to minimize the file size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, The .min files are the compressed version of raw file.  You do not have to add both. They provide both so that edits can be made to them but if you just want to include the bootstrap library you can use the .min files by themselves and you will be all set.